# iOS dial assist auto formats local number to USA number

Tags: iphone, ios, phone-number, nsnumberformatter

in my application am allowing the user to place call to customer support using this line of code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:18002096006"]]];
```

but iOS formats this to a USA number like below and makes call to USA

+1 (800) 209-6006

but this is an Indian toll free number.

....

I have seen the [same problem discussed from a ios user](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4791641?start=0&tstart=0), and resolved work around is to
disable "Dial Assist" in Settings > Phone

the problem is, there is no such option in iOS 7 and even if the user is using iOS6, we cant ask the user to change it in their settings, when they are making an emergency call..

Is there any work around for a developer to localize phone number and prevent auto formatting done by the iOS

Answer (score 1):

Add the correct country code in fron of it so it wont trigger the 'dial assist'