# Is it possible to turn off the dial assist feature in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-number

I am facing an issue while **dialing a call** as it is automatically assigning international or local prefixes when making calls for toll free local numbers Which starts with one to ISD

```
NSString *phNo = @"18605003000";
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phNo]];
NSLog(@"in call");
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
}
```

For above code, when Dail assist is **ON**, it is prefixing number and converting with +1 (860) 500-3000 which is actually a Indian toll free redirecting to ISD to call ..To avoid this I want to check whether Dail assist is **ON** or way to disable this programatically.

I have even referred this [iOS dial assist auto formats local number to USA number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183066/ios-dial-assist-auto-formats-local-number-to-usa-number) but this way it is Dailing to wrong number

So can any please suggest me for possible way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code, and had the dial assist on, but it dialed "18005003000" and did not converted to +1 (800) 500-3000

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://18005003000"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Yes,But the number which I have given is not a valid number toll free number which I m using..My toll free number has 1860 where I m getting this issue.Please find my updated question

Comment: ohk, its considering 18605003000 as a mobile number. Checking

Comment: Till far i have checked out, i was not able to find any code that get us a hand on Dial assist.